# Select all elements from one column in an array of arrays in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have an array of arrays:

```
arr = [["Foo1", "Bar1", "1", "W"], 
["Foo2", "Bar2", "2", "X"], 
["Foo3", "Bar3", "3", "Y"], 
["Foo4", "Bar4", "4", "Z"]]
```

And I want an array containing only the third column of each of the arrays:

```
res = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
```

How would I do that?

I want to type something like:

```
arr[][2]
```

But thinking more Ruby-like, I tried:

```
arr.select{ |r| r[2] }
```

but this returns the whole row.

Comment: Did you mean `arr.collect{ |r| r[2] }`?

Comment: Your `select` statement takes all the rows where the third element is truthy, that's why you don't get the expected result.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You want `arr.map {|row| row[2]}`

```
arr = [["Foo1", "Bar1", "1", "W"], 
["Foo2", "Bar2", "2", "X"], 
["Foo3", "Bar3", "3", "Y"], 
["Foo4", "Bar4", "4", "Z"]]

arr.map {|row| row[2]}
# => ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
```

Comment: Or `arr.map(&:third)` with Rails/ActiveSupport.

Comment: also `#first` and `#last` are available in plain ruby

Answer (score 17):

Another method:

```
arr.transpose[2]
```

Comment: For very large matrices, could `transpose` be more expensive than the `map {|r| r[2]}` solution?

Comment: @Jared Beck Memorywise I'd say yes, more expensive.

Comment: Thanks, I like this one a lot since you can use it without a block.  And if there were a need to get at the first and second column too (as I do) transpose can be used to setup the 'transposed' matrix all in one step.

Comment: @steenslag why would it be more expensive?

Comment: @JohnBachir for a n x m array, `transpose` has an m x n array as intermediate result; the map method results directly in a m x 1 array

Comment: @steenslag what do you mean by intermediate result? within the implementation? stepping back a little: are you and Jared saying it's more expensive because you know how ruby implements it, or because something inherent to the concept of transposition?

Answer (score 1):

Use map or collect 
arr.map { |a| a[2]}

Comment: There's no need for the `each` before `map`.